# How to make this query faster?

Tags: sql, performance, sqlite, unityscript

My Db look like this:

```
id | Column1 | Column2
```

Must known facts: id is not a primary unique id (but could be). id can go up to 2Millions+. Column values are filled with TINYINT

```
var query : String = "SELECT Column1 FROM Table1 WHERE Column1 <> 0";   
dbcmd = dbcon.CreateCommand();
dbcmd.CommandText = query; 
reader = dbcmd.ExecuteReader();
var result : int = 0;
while(reader.Read()) { 
    result++;
}
return result;
```

But for a basic search it makes up to 5 seconds, is there anyway to make it faster?

Edit: Like always, thanks for the contributors and the rapidity!

Comment: Are you _sure_ this is JavaScript and not, let's say ActionScript or TypeScript?

Comment: It's UnityScript, really similar to Javascript ( http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php?title=UnityScript_versus_JavaScript )

Comment: I re-tagged it as UnityScript, while UnityScript and JavaScript are very similar, they are in fact different languages

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This doesn't look like javascript code, but you could try counting the records instead of executing the query and then looping through the entire resultset on the client and increment a variable:

```
var query : String = "SELECT Count(Column1) FROM Table1 WHERE Column1 <> 0";
```

This will be much faster than your code because the count operation will be done by the database server directly.

Comment: Thanks! Any other suggestions?

Comment: No, that's the best performance you might ever hope to get from this operation. The `COUNT` SQL function is designed exactly for that purpose: counting the number of records that match some condition in the database. Every other solution would be a complete waste of resources.

Comment: Great, I'll give it a try!

Answer (score 7):

Yes, you are reading your results and processing them one by one. All you seem to be doing to need is the count, which you can get with:

```
"SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Table1 WHERE Column1 <> 0";
```

Comment: Thanks! Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, index the table on Column1, the row used in the where clause.

Comment: Is column1 unique? Do you have an primary index already defined for the table?

Comment: `CREATE UNIQUE INDEX col1_index_name ON Table1 ( column1 );`

Comment: `ALTER TABLE Table1 ADD INDEX (column1);`

Comment: I will do some searches on it. Thanks for the suggestion!